# Who is allowed to use Realm?

Tags: realm

Realm Core Binary License states:

"This product is not being made available to any person located in Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Sudan, Syria or the Crimea region, or to any other person that is not eligible to receive the product under U.S. law."

I cannot understand who is the person mentioned. Is it a developer who uses Realm API or a user of an application developed using Realm?

To make my question clear:
1) May a developer located in one of those areas use Realm to develop apps upon its API?
2) May a user located in one of those areas use a program developed with use of Realm?

Thanks for answering!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about legal/licencing, not a specific programming problem.

Comment: Sorry for that. I decided to ask here because Realm support ignored me.

Comment: Realm support "ignored you" over a weekend because we haven't been able to get the question answered by someone in authority, and I only noticed this SO issue in passing. I could give you my opinion but as a remote contractor it's not worth much. (We don't offer free support on weekends but I scan SO). Anyone speaking on Stack Overflow is not going to be able to give you a more legally valid answer than a Realm employee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for Realm in this regard but will try to get the question answered definitively.

As public fact, both Apple and Google ban distribution of apps to Crimea. Speaking as an individual, I think these sanctions are sad and a US action aimed at the wrong people.

I found [this article](http://rbth.com/science_and_tech/2015/02/04/crimean_software_developers_are_trying_to_bypass_sanctions_43441.html) interesting on how people are trying to cope with the sanctions.